# 500.19 error in IIS

Tags: iis, permissions

I've set up a site in IIS and even though the permissions on the folder are correct I still get "500.19 Cannot read configuration file due to insufficient permissions". To make it simple I've set full control (it's only for local use) instead of the "correct" permissions and they are set for authenticated users, system, my user account, administrators, iis_iusrs and my app pool. I've got these exact same permissions set on another computer and browsing the site works like charm on that one.

If I choose to runt the app pool as LocalSystem instead of ApplicationPoolIdentity the site load but without any of the static content (images, css, scripts, etc.).

Any idea what might be wrong here? Seems like a lot of people out there are having the exact same problem but no matter how much I search and read up on it there is no solution to be found.

Comment: It sounds like your static content files might not have inherited the permissions you've set on the parent folder. To blanket set the  permissions on all files and folders, go to the folder properties of the parent folder, click the security tab and select advanced, check the `Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object` then click Apply.

Comment: Also, set your App Pool to run as ApplicationPoolIdentity and then back to your folder permissions, add `IIS APPPOOL\nameofyourapppool` and grant full control.

Comment: @Tom Hall Clicking the "replace..." did it. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tom answered this question in his comment above but I don't know how to mark a comment as a solution. This is what he wrote:

"It sounds like your static content files might not have inherited the permissions you've set on the parent folder. To blanket set the permissions on all files and folders, go to the folder properties of the parent folder, click the security tab and select advanced, check the Replace all child object permission entries with inheritable permission entries from this object then click Apply."

Answer (score 0):

These problems can be tough to answer because so many different things could cause this. Many times more than one thing is wrong. However, there might be a simple solution.

If switching the app pool to LocalSystem works, that is a start. Regarding the subsequent problem, I would suggest checking the links in the webpage to be sure they are pointing to valid locations on the server. If so, and you are still having trouble, please reply with the version of IIS that you are using and the authentication method used for the site.

Comment: The links to scrpits and style sheets are correct but I get 404 when I click them. I wonder if I need to add something for static content?

What do you mean by authentication?

Comment: By the way, I'm in 7.5.

Comment: You shouldn't need to add anything for the embedded content as long as the referenced files are in a virtual directory or in the web application. Try to directly reference one of the files.

Comment: What I mean by authentication is the method the site is using. (ie: windows authentication, forms authentication, anonymous... )